# JavaFX to Regular Java Class Parameter Problem

Tags: java, parameters, event-handling, arguments, javafx

My aim is to create a small javafx application that makes use of javafx forms (handled by separate java classes) for example:  Login.fx (GUI) calls methods from LoginFunc.java. to handle user interactions.

My problem is that I need to pass the username and password entered by the user to LoginFunc.
Usually in swing applications i use a constructor such as

public LoginFunc (String username, String password) {
}

How can I call such a class from a javafx file? my current code is:

function btnLoginAction(): Void {
        var username: String;
        var password: String;
        **var login: LoginFunc;**

```
    username = txtUsername.text;
    password = txtPassword.text;
```

}

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I think you want to add this to `Login.fx`:

```
def loginButton = Button {
    action: btnLoginAction
}
function btnLoginAction(MouseEvent:e):Void {
    var username = txtUsername.text;
    var password = txtPassword.text;
    // construct new LoginFunc note the CURLY braces
    var login:LoginFunc = LoginFunc{};
    login.doSomething(username, password);
}
```

If I misinterpreted, please let me know.

Comment: Hi Eric! that's it! Thanks to you I've managed to pass 2 string vars to the constructor method of LoginFunc. lol, I'm used to regular Java code but I haven't managed to understand JavaFX script yet.

I am trying to redevelop my swing electronic patient record system in javafx (mainly for educational purposes).  I believe that JavaFX will be the next Swing in java user interfaces.

I have one other question.  It seems that whenever I click the login button, the function is executed but when I use the keyboard (using tabs and "click" using the spacebar the function is not executed)

Comment: The following is my current code


function btnLoginOnMouseClicked(event: javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent): Void {
        var username = txtUsername.text;
        var password = txtPassword.text;

        var login:LoginFunc = new LoginFunc(username, password);
        login.printDetails();
    }


Do I need to create a separate function for every possible event?  Please note that I am currently using Netbeans 6.9 with the JavaFX designer (I'm considering going back to basics and forget about the designer mainly to learn how it works behind the scenes)

I apologize for the long post :(

Thanks!

Comment: No, you can certainly reuse functions for different events, as long as the arguments are compatible. Glad it's working for you :)